# Ruby - cannot load such file -- curl - Windows 10

Tags: ruby, windows, curl, libcurl, curb

The things that i have done so far:
Downloaded: rubyinstaller-devkit-3.0.2-1-x86 32bit
added C:\Ruby30\bin to Path
Downloaded: curl-7.80.0-win32-mingw
added C:\curl-7.80.0-win32-mingw\bin to Path

I used the following command to install curb:
gem install curb -- -- --with-curl-lib=C:\curl-7.80.0-win32-mingw\bin –with-curl-include=C:\curl-7.80.0-win32-mingw\include

It was done: 1 gem installed.

I created the gemfile, went fine apart from seeing this:

Using bundler 2.2.22
Using curb 0.9.11
Fetching unidecoder 1.1.2

but when i wanted to run the ruby app i got this error message:

```
<internal:C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- curb (LoadError)
    from <internal:C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from crawler.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

When I type in curb --version
it gives me nothing: 'curb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Even if it was installed previously.
Any idea?

also run
gem install curb --verbose --platform=ruby -- --with-curl-lib=C:\curl-7.80.0-win32-mingw\lib --with-curl-include=C:\curl-7.80.0-win32-mingw\include

same load error

Comment: Once you have created a Gemfile, you need to install the gems listed inside it. Try running `bundle install`, and then run your script again (or `bundle exec ruby <your script>` if that still doesn't work).

Comment: @AaronChristiansen, Thank you . I know that step. the issue is not able to install curb. It is all about libcurl issue, need to download it and change the path etc.. however all the info are very old. Tried some of them but it is still not working.

Comment: @AaronChristiansen, I have updated my issue. Could you please have a look at?

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to solve it from here, sorry :( The most important part of that error output looks to be `Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)`, so I would try searching from there.

Comment: Thank you @AaronChristiansen, I have updated my question again.